# Using delta method (deviation of transformed variable)

Tags: delta-method

How can in prove the following statement with delta method:
"If I divide a variable by its deviation, the deviation of the transformed variable is 1."

Comment: This doesn't mean anything. I suppose you had standard deviation in mind, in that case delta method is pointless. Actually, it's always pointless for linear transformations

Comment: @carlo I think it is also useful for linear transformations, as even for transformations of the form $f(x) = a + bx$ it is true that $\sigma^{2}_{f(x)} \ne f(\sigma^{2}_{x})$, right? (I mean, the Delta method might be *trivial*, but still technically useful?)

Comment: delta method is an approximation based on Tailor decomposition. You don't need it for linear transformation. But yes, sure that it is true.